# Install Ubuntu on Lenovo S440

Tags: 14.04, laptop, lenovo

I'm getting really fed up of my current Windows 10 install on my Lenovo S440 ThinkPad (2.4 GHz processor, 8 Gb RAM, and a 16 Gb SSD swap drive), and would like to install Ubuntu 14.04 as a dual boot, to bring it in line with all my other devices. I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this kind of install, or could offer advice on where to start?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean a 160GB SSD drive?  16GB probably won't be big enough for both Windows 10 and Ubuntu.

If it is 160GB, then just download and burn the Ubuntu 14.04 iso to a DVD, and tell it to install alongside your Windows 10 OS.

Comment: No, IIRC, it's a small 16 Gb SSD in addition to the 160 ish Gb HDD, which Windows uses as a sort of swap file / SSD to hold the most commonly accessed parts of the OS. I would just burn a USB key and then hope for the best, but I'm a little worried about this SSD drive - do you think it's best to just go ahead and try installing and see what happens?

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

First, this can't be stressed enough; backup your data.  This is something that should be done regularly, to ensure that data loss is not a possibility.

Second, you could use Clonezilla on your drive as it is now, to make a backup of its current state.  This way, if the dual boot installation goes wrong, you would be able to restore the disk image to the drive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll clone my existing Windows 10 system using CloneZilla when I get back to London, then try and install from a USB pen drive, I'll let you know how it goes later this week!

Comment: Ok.  Hope it goes well.